# iOS: Calling Pan Gesture attached to a UIButton programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uibutton

When a user highlights a button in my horizontal scrollView, an identical looking button (Different draggable subclass) is added right above. What I'm trying to achieve is similar to lifting a card off a stack like Solitaire, and having another card underneath it.

Everything is working except that right now the moment the user highlights, the touch get's canceled as the new view come's into place. The user has to lift their finger off and tap again to register that the dragging event has begin. What I want to do is to automatically pass the touch from the first button to the newly added button without the user having to remove their finger again and touching the new button. I'm not even sure if this is possible.

Maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way, but the reason I don't make the first button the draggable button is because I reuse it in my horizontal scrollView.

Answer (score 0):

Which I feel you should consider each card as a custom `UIView` and handle

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event;
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(nullable UIEvent *)event;
```

to show selection, dragging and finally placing of a card. So all logic for selection and put card would in one custom `UIView` class. For all other validation do that in your parent `UIViewController`